# React:TSLint - Ban the mac 'smart quote' character?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

One of our designers likes to use mac smart quotes/apostrophes in his mockups, but we don't want them showing up ANYWHERE in the code. Is there a way to create a rule using TSLint that will warn (or even ban) specific characters like this from the entire codebase?

Smart quote example: `you’ll`

Dumb quote example: `you'll`

As you can see, it's pretty hard to see the difference and catch them in real time. They don't cause errors, but for consistency we don't want them finding their way in from copy/pastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no rule that provides character banning. You can write custom rule as described in the [documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40394298/3639633 .